# how to set xPage page style through styleClas rather than style

Tags: css, xpages, lotus-notes

I want to set entire page background color and this example works fine:

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    style="background-color:#f1f1f1;">
</xp:view>
```

But when I try to set it through styleClass it doesn't:

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" 
    styleClass="myPage">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:styleSheet href="/myStyle.css"></xp:styleSheet>
    </xp:this.resources>
</xp:view>

//myStyle.css
.myPage{
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
}
```

In Notes Designer you can see that background-color does apply to the page but it doesn't work in browser

Answer (score 2):

Your little example does work for me. The background is gray in browser.

Have a look at browser's developer tools console. Maybe you get a hint what's the problem there.

If you use a **bootstrap** theme though then background-color gets overwritten by bootstrap.
[image]

Add

```
body.xsp {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

to your file myStyle.css in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing a dedicated stylesheet called myStyle.css. You therefore need to create a stylesheet in Resources - Style Sheets called myStyle.css and add your CSS to this file.

Right now you are using an inline style sheet and your reference to myStyle.css therefore has no effect (unless the file exists, of course).